# Filtering multiple values with isotopo

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use a isotope plugin to filter a content using a  with this official example:

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/jubmr

But, I want to use multiple filters in the value attr and I have no ideia how I can do that. Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Example:

Demo:

```
 <option value=".metal">metal</option>
```

What I want:

```
 <option value=".metal .alkali">metal</option>
```

Comment: Here is some info on isotope [combination filters](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#combination-filters)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to combine both selectors like so

```
<option value=".metal.alkali">metal</option>
```

While I've never used this extension before,  it appears to use the CSS  selector syntax also used in jQuery:

- Spaces between class names (or any selector) denotes hierarchy  (second class occurs on element that is descendent of first class).
- Commas between selectors act as "or" operations
- The "and" syntax is achieved by having neither spaces nor commas.

  li#SomeId.class-one.class-two

Would select a list item that had the ID SomeId and both class names (class-one and class-two).